# High-availability Redis?

Tags: redis, high-availability

I am currently setting up an infrastructure for an App in AWS. App is written in Django and is using Redis for some transactions. High availability is key for this application and I am having a hard time trying to get my head around how to configure Redis for High availability.

Application level changes are not an option.

Ideally I would like to have a redis setup, to which I can write and read and replicate and scale when required.

Current Setup is a Redis Fail-over scenario with `HAProxy --> Redis Master --> Replica Slave.`

Could someone guide me understand various options ? and how to scale redis for high availability !

Comment: Why don't you use redis cluster?

Comment: I am considering it.. How should I approach the high availability ? I am a novice on redis.. trying to read through and get my head around how I can get this right..

Comment: Depends on what exactly you mean by "high availability". Are there any specific requirements?

Comment: Currently the application uses Redis to store and retrieve certain keyvalue pairs (that are persistent as well), it is a very simple setup. We are currently trying to build a redis cluster that would scale with the needs (for example, if there is a surge of users, we should be horizontally scale and serve the data from multiple masters) - I guess this is a typical scaling requirement

Comment: "I guess this is a typical scaling requirement" - yes, but it has nothing to do with high availability. Availability is a property of a system, which tries its best to accept and respond to requests (stay available), even when part of its nodes are unreachable/failed/etc. Often, availability implies eventual consistency (that is, your db might serve stale data, but for your app stale data might be better than no data at all)

Comment: yes, you are right.. I was not clearly explaining things.. we need maximum availability (stay available, even if it is stale)..

I am now testing out a simple redis cluster with 3 server (3 masters and 3 slaves distributed among the 3 servers), I need to figure out a way to make it scalable and highly available based on high-demand..

Comment: the data stored in redis are persistent data, and the users depend on them for certain features. If a node fails the data should be served from a secondary node (for failover) and if the master is exhausted with so much traffic; then it would be nice to have the ability to add more master nodes, to the cluster and get all of them respond to customer requests at the same time (read and write)..

Comment: "if the master is exhausted with so much traffic" - a single redis process can handle tens to hundreds thousand operations per second. Your app must be HUGE to saturate even one process.

Comment: Do you think a simple Master --> Slave (replica) with an HAProxy handling the fail-over should suffice ? the app is currently in development and is expecting to replace an existing app with an expected surge in traffic (about 2K active users per second)

Comment: currently we are using a small t2.medium aws instance for our development activities (for redis), we will move to mr.large instances in production.

Comment: It's really hard to say without knowing specifics of your app.

Comment: Yes - I understand. I will try experimenting with the cluster and see how it works, and then workout from there.. Thank you for your patience with me.

Comment: but what confuses me is with most redi setups things look like failover - high availability becomes an issue ? ( how could i just have couple masters and load balance the writes and reads to them while maintaining availability even if one master fails and the requests are redirected to a secondary master! )

Comment: "secondary master" - what is this? Is this the slave of now-failed master? Or is it the other master that is still up?

Comment: it is a second master that is still up..

Comment: but why redirect requests to it? It doesn't have the data of the other master.

Comment: can we turn this into chat ? so we can discuss this in more detail ?

Comment: The link doesn't appear for me. If you can create the chat, go ahead. Ah, I think, it's because of your low rep. you can't chat.

Comment: I settled on a redis cluster, for now - the whole thing is super complex.. I might have to get some help with planning on high availability for it.. need to leave that for now.. and may be read up more and experiment more with redis before revisiting scalability for redis..

Comment: yes - it looks like it..

Comment: I just configured a 3 node cluster with redis.. I need to test this out and see how things work.. 3 masters and 3 slaves in the cluster..

Answer (score 1):

Use AWS ElastiCache Redis Cluster with Multi-AZ. They provides automatic fail-over. It provides endpoint to access master node.

If master goes down AWS route your endpoint to another node. everything happens automatically, you don't have to do anything.

Just make sure that if you are doing DNS to IP caching in your application, its set to 60 seconds or so instead of default.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoFailover.html

Thanks,
KS